# How to model this system of $^{238}\,U$ atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

An exercise from *The Physics of Quantum Mechanics by James Binney and David Skinner*
[image]

I am now tying to solve this question. I cn find out the probability of trasmission and rebouncing for that $\alpha$ particle. **However, how can I use the condition "speed~ $c/3$"?** Should I consider states of well defined momentum? I am looking forward to getting an idea about how to approach this question.

**Also, why do we want to find $W$?** Should I consider states with well defined parity?

Comment: The $c/3$ assumption tells you how many times during the mean life of the nucleus the $\alpha$ bounces back from the barrier before it finally tunnels through.

Comment: The speed of the particle also directly tells you what the kinetic energy is. To understand why $W$ is relevant, hint: $2m/\hbar^2$ is (1/over) the prefactor in kinetic energy.